# Backpropagation for Neural Network - Python

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation, feed-forward

I am writing a program to do neural network in python I am trying to set up the backpropagation algorithm.  The basic idea is that I look through 5,000 training examples and collect the errors and find out in which direction I need to move the thetas and then move them in that direction.  There are the training examples, then I use one hidden layer, and then an output layer.  However I am getting the gradient/derivative/error wrong here because I am not moving the thetas correct as they need to be moved.  I put 8 hours into this today not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks for your help!!

```
x = 401x5000 matrix

y = 10x5000 matrix   # 10 possible output classes, so one column will look like [0, 0, 0, 1, 0... 0] to indicate the output class was 4

theta_1 = 25x401

theta_2 = 10x26


alpha=.01

    sigmoid= lambda theta, x: 1 / (1 + np.exp(-(theta*x)))


        #move thetas in right direction for each iteration
        for iter in range(0,1):
            all_delta_1, all_delta_2 = 0, 0
            #loop through each training example, 1...m    
            for t in range(0,5000):

                hidden_layer = np.matrix(np.concatenate((np.ones((1,1)),sigmoid(theta_1,x[:,t]))))
                output_layer = sigmoid(theta_2,hidden_layer)

                delta_3 = output_layer - y[:,t]
                delta_2= np.multiply((theta_2.T*delta_3),(np.multiply(hidden_layer,(1-hidden_layer))))

                #print type(delta_3), delta_3.shape, type(hidden_layer.T), hidden_layer.T.shape
                all_delta_2 += delta_3*hidden_layer.T
                all_delta_1 += delta_2[1:]*x[:,t].T



            delta_gradient_2 = (all_delta_2 / m)
            delta_gradient_1 = (all_delta_1 / m)
            theta_1 = theta_1- (alpha * delta_gradient_1)
            theta_2 = theta_2- (alpha * delta_gradient_2)
```

Comment: thanks for the edit blender.

also for clarity i want to add that my delta_gradient_2, and delta_gradient_1 are the right matrix sizes.  it is just that their values are inaccurate.  when i increase the iterations to 20 and measure the accuracy with a cost function the cost will go down for about 20 iterations and then start coming back up again.  but even at the lowest cost level the theta's my algorithm gives are not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your gradients are with respect to the unsquashed output layer.

Try changing `output_layer = sigmoid(theta_2,hidden_layer)` to `output_layer = theta_2*hidden_layer`.

Or recompute the gradients for squashed output.